# Metric(TFM) file not found

Tags: otftotfm

I want to build a LaTeX file, but when I do I get the following error:

```
Font U/bbold/m/n/10.95=bbold11 at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
```

I have searched everywhere on the internet and have tried to build various LaTeX files, but still get the same error message. Does anyone know how to solve this error, because it doesn't tell me anything.

I use the MikTex package and have uninstalled it and installed it again. I have restarted my pc. I hope you can give a solution, because I don't know anymore.

Comment: the font doesn't work for me neither, in miktex some input file is missing and in texlive it loops. Better don't use it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for your answer. How do I disable it?

Comment: as you didn't show any code it is not possible to say.

Comment: You don't want to reinstall MiKTeX. Rather, fire up its wizard and ask for installing `bbold` and `bbold-type1`.